# Increasing the size of axis labels in a Wireframe Plot

Tags: r, lattice

I want to adjust the size of the text in the axis labels of the wireframe method in R (found in the lattice package).

It seems like it *should* just be a matter of specifying

```
cex.lab=2
```

as is the case with most other plots. However, this does not increase the font size.

For example:

```
some_data <- expand.grid(c(1:10), c(1:10))
some_data$z <- sin(some_data$Var1 + some_data$Var2)
wireframe(z~Var1*Var2, some_data, scales=list(arrows=FALSE, cex=1.5), xlab='blah1', ylab='blah2', zlab='blah3')
wireframe(z~Var1*Var2, some_data, scales=list(arrows=FALSE, cex=1.5), xlab='blah1', ylab='blah2', zlab='blah3', cex.lab=4)
```

should produce a second plot with axis labels 4 times larger than the ones in the first. Instead they are identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways, there might be others:

```
wireframe(z~Var1*Var2, some_data, 
            trellis.par.set(list(axis.text=list(cex=2))), 
            scales=list(arrows=FALSE), 
            xlab='blah1', ylab='blah2', zlab='blah3')
```

The canonical reference for this is Sarkar's "Lattice" text and this is described in the Parameter System chapter on pages 126-128.

It also appears that you can use nested arguments within `scales`. Drop the par.settings call and use this instead:

```
..., scales=list(arrows=FALSE, axis=list(text=list(cex=2))), ...
```